# How could I view packaged APK files in Eclipse unencrypted?

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, app-inventor

I am newer to android development. I have a couple apps I've made with appinventor. I would like to be able to take a completed and packaged .apk that is saved on my computer that was made with appinventor and open to edit it in eclipse. Mainly I want to see how a working app Ive made is actually written. This is for my own educational purposes only, no pirating or other illegal uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally it is not possible to convert an *App Inventor* project into Java. However there are projects which have this goal, see [the App Inventor-Java translation project](http://code.google.com/p/appinventor-java-translation/) and [the Java Bridge project](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/apptomarket/lZNP4VPuxhQ/yVEBcRtTOdUJ).

Answer (score 0):

Check the [android-apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/). I have no experience with the tool and as I see it will not show you the sources but it seems to be the best way to 'unpack' apk files.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is possible, how are you going to bring the dex code back to your java code, even then, AppInventor makes for horrible APKs, two apps that do the exact same thing will differ greatly in size if made with the SDK vs AppInventor.

You should just read a couple of books, or search for information online, instead of trying to unpack an APK.

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely possible using [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) which involves a little time to set up and run but it give you a .jar that you can open with a [java decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/). As for getting the source files into eclipse, there are probably some decompilers that do this but probably cost money. You can use the one listed to copy/paste the code out but it will not provide you with an eclipse project.

Comment: The question was about [App Inventor](http://www.appinventor.mit.edu/). App Inventor does not generate Java code. Therefore your answer is not correct.

Comment: @Taifun - Per App Inventor - "App Inventor, you must "package" the app to produce an application package (apk file)." My solution is app inventor apk >> dex2jar >> .jar >> decompiler to .java. It is possible, if you understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: App Inventor generates yail. You can read the yail (Scheme) source.  I am not sure if it would be useful to look at the decompiled .jar from the .apk @rubber mallet. You can but you would be looking at code that was generated to run Scheme.  Taifun's suggestions in his answer has some pointers if you want to learn more by looking at Java code. The Java-Bridge is the one I would look at.